# How to use the jinja2 output as an ansible directive instead of a chain of characters?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am currently displaying some vars with 'extract':

```yaml
- name: Display hostvars over conditional
  hosts: all

  tasks:   
        - debug: 
            msg: "{{
              ansible_play_hosts
              | map('extract', hostvars, inventory_hostname)
              |selectattr('ansible_distribution', 'regex', 'Rocky|CentOS' )
              |selectattr('ansible_distribution_major_version', '==', '8' )
              |flatten
            }}"
```

The result is a list of name that match to those conditions:

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [ancolie-lba] => {
    "msg": [
        "vm703-dev"
    ]
}
```

and now I'd like to template this display with jinja2 ansible_facts.j2

```
{{'{{'}}
ansible_play_hosts
|map('extract', hostvars)
{% for condition in conditions %}
|selectattr('{{condition.attribute}}', '{{condition.verb}}', '{{condition.text}}' )
{% endfor %}
|flatten
{{'}}'}}
```

So as to use the jinja2 output file like follow:

```yaml
        - block:
            - name: generate a conf
              template: 
                src: ansible_facts.j2
                dest: /tmp/ansible_facts
            - debug:
                msg: "{{lookup('file', '/tmp/ansible_facts')}}"
          tags: template
          delegate_to: localhost
          vars:
            conditions:
              - attribute: 'ansible_distribution'
                verb: 'regex'
                text: 'Rocky|CentOS'
              - attribute: 'ansible_distribution_major_version'
                verb: '=='
                text: '8'
```

But it seems that ansible interprets the lookup output as a chain character instead of excuting the filters as initially:

What is returned:

```json
    "msg": "{{ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, os)|selectattr('ansible_distribution', 'regex', 'Rocky|CentOS' )|selectattr('ansible_distribution_major_version', '==', '8' )|flatten}}"
```

Expected result:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ancolie-lba] => {
    "msg": [
        "vm703-dev"
    ]
}
```

How to use the jinja2 output as an ansible directive instead of a chain of characters?

Comment: you dont show any output, we couldn' reproduce the problem...could you show the different output and the result you want..

Comment: added some precisions. The playbook is straightforward, you can test with any hosts.

Comment: Could you pinpoint exactly how you end up with the "templated display" In  _/tmp/ansible_facts_ and what is in _ansible_facts.j2_?

Comment: I do not see any way in which your `extract` example could have resulted in the output you provided. The `map()` attempts to retrieve a variable named after `inventory_host` from each of the `hostvars` that it extracts, which will normally fail. If that somehow succeeds and the `selectattr()` calls work then the final output will not be a list of simple strings, because strings do not have the attributes you are testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to produce a Jinja template as the result of your template, then somehow induce Ansible to re-do the templating that it thinks is already complete. This might be technically possible to achieve, but is fighting against Ansible's Jinja integration instead of working with it.

As long as you have at least Jinja 2.10 (for `namespace()` support) you can do this in a fairly straightforward way with no double-templating. It may also be doable on older versions, but would be more of a pain.

`test.j2`:

```
{% set ns = namespace(result=(ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars))) %}
{% for condition in conditions %}
{% set ns.result = ns.result | selectattr(condition.attribute, condition.verb, condition.text) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ ns.result | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | to_nice_yaml }}
```

`test.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'test.j2') | from_yaml }}"
      run_once: true
      vars:
        conditions:
          - attribute: ansible_facts.hostname
            verb: match
            text: pe
```

Output:

```
PLAY [all] ************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************ok: [rotten-rusalka.authz-relay.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [persistent-servitor.relay-egress.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [bounteous-abumiguchi.mx.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [worthy-yithian.vdc-relay.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [commutual-chthonian.syslog.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [yern-elderthing.authz-static.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [diligent-griffin.authn-relay.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [dauntless-ratthing.dnsbl.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [powerful-yithian.covid-relay.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [legible-sansei.egress.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [dominant-shantak.dnsbl.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [trustworthy-dhole.jail.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [rose-dobyoshi.mx.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [pear-kaichigo.mx.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [pandora.x.mail.umich.edu]
ok: [queenly-kuzunoha.egress.x.mail.umich.edu]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************$
ok: [worthy-yithian.vdc-relay.x.mail.umich.edu] => {
    "msg": [
        "persistent-servitor.relay-egress.x.mail.umich.edu",
        "pear-kaichigo.mx.x.mail.umich.edu"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what expected.